# execute aws command in script with sudo

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, command-line-interface

I am running a `bash` script with `sudo` and have tried the below but am getting the error below using `aws cp`. I think the problem is that the script is looking for the `config` in `/root` which does not exist. However doesn't the `-E` preserve the original location? Is there an option that can be used with `aws cp` to pass the location of the `config`. Thank you :).

```
sudo -E bash /path/to/.sh
   - inside of this script is `aws cp`
```

**Error**

```
The config profile (name) could not be found


I have also tried `export` the name profile and `source` the path to the `config`
```

Comment: Have you tried to put all in the same directory(script,file to copy,etc.)?

Comment: So the script is called from one directory.... creates a bunch on new directories and copies all the new directories to `aws`. If I do not use `sudo` the `aws cp` is fine and returns no errors.... the problem is I need `sudo` to create the new directories. The original `config` file in `$HOME/user/aws`. Thank you :).

Comment: Are the new directories in a protected path? In this case cannot you add the user to the same group?

Comment: the directories are in a protected path and I do not think adding user  to the same group can be done, but I will check. Short of that are there other options? Maybe I could `export HOME=/root` and copy `$HOME/user/.aws`  to  `/root/.aws`, so there are two directories with credentials. I don't think this will cause issues? Thank you :).

Comment: Yes you can also do it, or simply create a symlink from /root/.aws to /home/user/.aws

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the original user like :

```
sudo -u $SUDO_USER aws cp ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also run the script using `source` instead of `bash` -- using `source` will cause the script to run in the same shell as your open terminal window, which will keep the same env together (such as user) - though honestly, @Philippe answer is the better, more correct one.